# Can the moderator candidate nomination display order be randomized?

Tags: feature-request, election

Currently, the nominations are displayed in reverse chronological order on the time the candidate submitted their name.  This seems to disadvantage those who were quickest to submit their nomination.  We all know there are problems with chronological sorting (as discussed frequently with regarding to first answers having an advantage over more complete, later answers).  At least with respect to answers to questions, one hopes the voting mechanism will ultimately sort the better answers to the top.  In this election / nomination process there is no such sorting mechanism, leaving the first nominees at a permanent disadvantage.  With only 7 candidate right now it isn't *so* bad (though I can imagine plenty of people not making it to the end of the list), but if the number of candidates were to get into the high teens it seems very likely some of the candidate profiles would get lost at the bottom of the list.

So can the nominee profiles / blurbs be displayed in random order when the election page is opened?

Comment: Another option is to have the list of candidates displayed *before* the "abstract" of their campaign.

Comment: I'll only note that the randomization of display order is implemented in the election proper, though.

Answer (score 4):

If you access the information via [the election page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/), sort "random" is an option (default?).

Comment: I meant that the order on the nominations page (the one linked from the main math.SE) *should* be randomized.  I agree your answer gives a way that I could see them randomized if I wanted to.  I would guess most users click on the link from math.SE and get the chronological listing; hence, the bias against early movers.

Comment: I don't know if having to scroll down creates a *bias*... in any case nominations can be [bumped](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/139059/revisions) to the top, for nominees who are concerned with such things.